# MATLAB Plot depending Variable in ode

Tags: matlab, ode45

I've a problem in MATLAB. I try to plot a variable inside the ode function. I call my ode Funktion with this code:

```
%Above is the code for the IC and constants
%Initial conditions [x0, vx0, y0, vy0]
IC = [x_0; w_x; y_0; w_y];
%Simulationszeitvektor
tspan = 0:dt:Tsim;
%Anonymous Function 
a =@(t,z) Parabel(z,m,g,u_x,u_y,r_p,A,rho_L,nv);
%Options
options = odeset('Events',@Ereignis,'Refine',4,'RelTol', 1e-12);
%Solver
[t,z] = ode45(a,tspan, IC, options);
```

The Problem is the Reynolds-Number Re. The Reynolds-Number is depending on the velocity. The velocity is decreasing during the drag. The Drag is depending on the Reynolds-Number. The velocity is calculate with the ode45 solver from matlab. The function file looks like this:

```
%My Function File
function dz = Parabel(z,m,g,u_x,u_y,r_p,A,rho_L,nv)
dz = zeros (4,1);
% relativ velocity
% z(2) is the velocity in x-direction
% z(4) is the velocity in y-direction
v_x=z(2)-u_x; 
v_y=z(4)-u_y;
v=sqrt(v_x^2+v_y^2);
% Calculation Reynoldszahl
Re = (2*r_p*v)/nv;
%Drag Force
F_k = Re*constant
dz(2) = -F_k*constant;
dz(4) = -F_k*constant-g;
%The other code part is not necessary
```

What I want to do, is to plot the Reynolds-Number Re, because I really need to know the Number. I don't know how i can do this. 
I need to save Re in the workspace, like the variable z.

Comment: Why not calculate it after the solution and plot that: `Re = (2*r_p*sqrt(z(:,2).^2+z(:,4).^2))/nv`?

Comment: That works for me, right now. Maybe somebody knows another solution